# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException on Facebook MVC Application demo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm actually following this article to try facebook app development : http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app

When I launch the app, I first got the authorization popup asking me for information access, but when I press "Ok" and fb load my page, I got the following exception :

```
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +11165993
    Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook.PermissionsStatus.ConvertApiResult(IList`1 apiResults) +134
    Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook.Providers.DefaultFacebookPermissionService.GetUserPermissionsStatus(String userId, String accessToken) +79
    Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook.Authorization.FacebookAuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +3091
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +97
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I've tried twice to setup the projet, same issues.
My fb app id, app secret and app namespace are set correctly.
Regarding the stacktrace, I suspect some sort of authorization issues, but as I'm a total newbie to fb development, I have no idea of what could be wrong and google didn't helped me that much.

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT 1**

I've updated my nuget references for the facebook API as I suspect FB changed their API and the return code for the permission status isn't known by the library... without success, still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook library. I patched the lib and send the fix to the AspNetMvcStack team for review/integration.
Everything is explained in the ticket :)

Ticket : https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2241